# Docusign How to set a locked tag view by all recipients

Tags: docusignapi

I want to create tags that are view by all recipients, but at the same time are locked.

For example, A document with 4 recipients  (3 signers and 1 CC) send in orders 1,2,3,4.  I want a tag allowing the sender to enter the contract unit price, obviously the sender wants to allow all recipients be able to see the tag with the contract price, but do not wan any of the recipients manipulating or changing the data.

I considered using the NOTE tag or is better to use a regular text tag with the Edit by All feature on but with the data in lock mode?

Comment: Can you assign only to the sender (are they already as signer?) and use routing order so that they are 1st and all other recipients are 2nd or greater?  That way they can never see it without the sender having already filled it in, and it's not assigned to any of them.

Comment: NO.. The sender is no a signer. And even is he was .. his input does not propagate to the other recipients.  In fact, I tried using the tag assigned to the first recipients, but this does not help, because the recipients after the first one do not get to see that the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the "Display SecureField initial value to all recipients" account setting to CHECKED in order for all recipients to see the value populated in these tabs. Mark the tabs as 'locked' in order to prevent any of the recipients from editing the values.